# yard and annotate for models in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, annotate, yard

I am trying to use the annotate gem with the -f yard option. This works quite well for models in the toplevel of the folder. However a lot of my models are in a namespace. The annotate gem will create the information on top of the file and yard is not picking that up as a description of the model.

Is there a way to bring the annotation directly in front of the class?

```
bundle exec annotate --models -f yard
```

Leads to

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: a_bs
#
# @!attribute id
#   @return []
# @!attribute date
#   @return [Date]
# @!attribute created_at
#   @return [Time]
# @!attribute updated_at
#   @return [Time]
module A
  class B < ApplicationRecord
  end
end
```

Comment: I strongly doubt it. I don't think the gem actually parses the file beyond just finding existing annotations and replacing them. You can find the options here https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/#options

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is also my impression. I read the list but wondered if I missed something. Or maybe someone has a clever workaround :) Anyway if this is not possible the value of the -f yard option is rather limited...